# Stuck on Loading after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: boot, 20.04

I upgraded my Ubuntu version yesterday from `18.04` to `20.04`.

Yesterday it was working fine, even after reboot.

Today, when I try to boot, I'm stuck on this loading screen:

[image: ubunbtu]

I tried rebooting, waiting, to no avail.

Comment: There are many questions and answers in AskUbuntu about similar problems. Which of them have you tried so far and what results did you obtain? Please [edit] your question and elaborate.

Comment: @guiverc, I meant 18.04. I edited the question.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli, I somehow made it work, even though I don't know why it works. I posted an answer

Answer (score 0):

I tried rebooting after waiting 15 minutes for the loading to end, but the same thing occurred again.

Since I have my machine on dual boot, I tried booting first to Windows, and then reboot to Ubuntu. That seemed to work.

PS: I don't know why booting to Windows, then restart and boot to Ubuntu worked. Maybe someone else can elaborate on that.

**Edit: This solution doesnt work anymore.**

Comment: You should press Escape during the boot screen and determine what startup screen is hanging. Maybe a `fsck` is being run..

Comment: @FedonKadifeli the solution is not working anymore. If I press Escape before loading Ubuntu I'm directed to the grub terminal screen

Comment: Press the Escape key *after* the grub screen disappears. It will show you the *init* scripts as they run. And you will see what script takes too much time...