# Installing Ubuntu 20.04 dual boot on External HDD (With existing Windows7 OS) on UEFI Thinkpad E475 Laptop with Internal HDD (Windows10)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

how can i properly install Ubuntu on mt external HDD without any failure/errors.

I have an old HDD which has Windows7 OS on it. Lets call this "old HDD" as "External HDD".

On my thinkpad E475 laptop, has an internal HDD runs Windows 10 OS.
It is also an UEFI mode. It has a 2core AMD A6-9500B processor base 2.3Ghz, AMD R5 Radeon Graphics with 8gb ram.

I want to keep my windows7 OS on the external HDD and install ubuntu 20.04. When I plug in my external HDD and turn on my laptop, i want to be able to choose the OS (win7/ubuntu) to boot into. If external HDD not plugged in, then boot windows10 as per normal.

My external HDD has 500gb for windows7 and i have allocated 300gb freespace for Ubuntu.

The reason why i need ubuntu OS so badly is because i need it for school project (Openvino software) which i had worked on in school ubuntu PCs but due to covid everyones working from home. Furthermore, my laptop of 8gb ram is too slow to run Ubuntu on a VM (virtualbox/vmware), running openvino on the ubuntu VM would be even worst it would be impossible to work on my laptop.

On my first failed attempt, booting into my Live USB with internal HDD inside my laptop and external HDD plugged in, the drive names were in gparted:
external hdd (800gb) - /dev/sds
internal hdd (500gb) - /dev/sdb
USB (16gb) - /dev/sdc

To double confirm i even unplugged external HDD and it showed :
Internal hdd (500gb) - /dev/sdb
usb (16gb) - /deb/sdc

following these two guides, i got errors couldnt get canocinal path of cow when i tried sudo update-grub. I tried to fix this by mounting (i got confused about mounting)

Despite this, i removed USB stick, turned on my laptop and pressed f12, seleted "external HDD" to boot from and it displayed grub version (xxx), cant remember but definitely grub. Not grub2. Which gave me a few options (ubuntu+, windows boot mgr (sdb) , windows boot mgr (??), advanced options for ubuntu) As i booted into ubuntu+, it stuck on the loading screen for more than 10mins (probably due to AMD graphics)

I rebooted to ubuntu+, press e, tried quiet splash, quiet nosplash, quiet splash $vf... , quiet splash $vf.. nomodeset, yet i would get black screen after the complilation in terminal completes.

1.https://www.58bits.com/blog/2020/02/28/how-create-truly-portable-ubuntu-installation-external-usb-hdd-or-ssd

2.https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step
3 .https://www.zachpfeffer.com/single-post/install-ubuntu-on-an-external-hard-drive

Subsequent readings online made me even confuse how to install ubuntu. This is really frustrating!!

4.https://superuser.com/questions/1467480/install-bootable-ubuntu-on-external-ssd-without-changing-windows-10/1467514#1467514

5.https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.techrepublic.com/google-amp/article/how-to-properly-automount-a-drive-in-ubuntu-linux/

6.https://askubuntu.com/questions/1283390/stuck-on-loading-after-upgrade-to-20-04

7 https://linuxconfig.org/amd-radeon-ubuntu-20-04-driver-installation

To properly install ubuntu on my external HDD , should i,

1. Remove internal HDD from laptop
2. Plug in usb and external hdd, boot from usb
3. Choose ubuntu+/ubuntu(safe graphics)?
4. Try ubuntu, select "something else", in "unallocated partition" of SDA (which external HDD is named), create 3 partitions
   (can anyone kindly advise me which partitions i should make, i am confused about creating partitons (efi/root/home/swap), the need to mounting them, choosing bootloader installation.

Currently, my external HDD as /dev/sda has 4 used partions named
Sda1,2,3,5 all under windows.

If i make the following:
(500mb efi as "unallocated" + change flags to "boot esp",
3gb ext4 as root "/",
150gb home ext4 as "/home",
16gb "linux-swap" )
Bootloader installation I'm not sure. I woulx choose /dev/sda (external HDD itself)

It would be saved as sda4(efi),sda6(ext4 root),sda7(ext4 home),sda8(swap).

5.After installation, i would have to install the amdgpu/cpu supported graphics card for ubuntu right? If so, how can i install them properly to ensure my ubuntu runs properly?

Pleaze help!! I'm at my wits end and im really frustrated trying to install ubuntu taking entire day yet doesnt work!!!

Comment: set your bios order or otherwise move external hdd to the first boot position. if still cannot boot try to fix the boot using boot-repair(ppa:yannubuntu) in live cd. alternative way is install ubuntu in virtualbox on windows

Comment: Windows will not boot from an external drive. Your internal Windows is UEFI on gpt partitioning. Is Windows 7 UEFI or BIOS, most were BIOS which requires MBR(msdos) partitioning. Best not to mix boot modes on same system or all UEFI or all BIOS. You can boot both but only from UEFI boot menu. If you convert external to UEFI boot with gpt, Windows 7 will not boot even if drive moved to internal drive. Best to just retire Windows 7 as it is EoL anyway. https://askubuntu.com/questions/913716/dual-boot-on-separate-drives-best-configuration